# Which Emoji characters work as Swift identifiers?

Tags: swift, xcode, emoji

I noticed that I can use emoji as a Swift identifier:

```
let  = "happy"
let  = "sad"
print(value == 0 ?  : ) // prints "happy" or "sad"
```

However some emoji don't work:

```
let ✏️ = editDataSource // "Expected pattern" compile error
```

How do I know which emoji I can and cannot use as a Swift identifier?

Note: Obviously you would want to use emoji with care since it's not very readable, but this question is not about that; it's about if you do want to use Emoji, which ones can you use?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like Emoji is split up into many blocks in Unicode, and that the allowed/disallowed set is roughly correlated with the block in which the character exists.

For example, if you look at the [Unicode Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks), you'll notice that most of the emoticons ( - ) are in the range `U+1F600 - U+1F64F`, all of which seem to work as Xcode identifiers.

On the other hand, the ⛔ symbol is in the Miscellaneous Symbols (`U+2600 - U+26FF`) section, which seems to have no emojis that work.

Here are some of the major Emoji Unicode Blocks:

```
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
| Unicode Block                         | Works? | Start   | End     | Sample |
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
| Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs | Yes    | U+1F300 | U+1F5FF |  |
| Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs  | Yes    | U+1F900 | U+1F9FF |  |
| Emoticons                             | Yes    | U+1F600 | U+1F64F |  |
| Transport and Map Symbols             | Yes    | U+1F680 | U+1F6FF |  |
| Miscellaneous Symbols                 | No     | U+2600  | U+26FF  | ⚽⛔⛱ |
| Dingbats                              | No     | U+2700  | U+27BF  | ✅✋❗ |
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Tip: You can use http://getemoji.com to get the emoji with a space after the emoji. This makes it easy to match an emoji using the regex `\S+\s`.

To find an emoji's Unicode value you can copy it to your clipboard then search for it on http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Here is a list of many of the emoji. If the line is commented out, it couldn't be compiled as of Xcode 8. (You should be able to use find on this page as well.)

```
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☺️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☹️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ‍❤️‍ = 1
//let ‍❤️‍ = 1
let  = 1
//let ‍❤️‍‍ = 1
//let ‍❤️‍‍ = 1
let  = 1
let ‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let ‍‍‍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛑ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☝️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✌️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✊ = 1
//let ✋ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☘ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⭐️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✨ = 1
//let ☄ = 1
//let ☀️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛅️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☁️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛈ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚡️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❄️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❄️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ☃️ = 1
//let ⛄️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☂️ = 1
//let ☔️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☕️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚽️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚾️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛳️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛷ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛸ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛹ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✈️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛵️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛴ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚓️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛽️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛲️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛰ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛺️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛪️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛩ = 1
//let ⌚️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⌨ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☎️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⏱ = 1
//let ⏲ = 1
//let ⏰ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⏳ = 1
//let ⌛️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚖ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚒ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛏ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚙ = 1
//let ⛓ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚔ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☠ = 1
//let ⚰ = 1
//let ⚱ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚗ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛱ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✉️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✂️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ✒️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ✏️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❤️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❣️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☮ = 1
//let ✝️ = 1
//let ☪ = 1
let  = 1
//let ☸ = 1
//let ✡️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☯️ = 1
//let ☦ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛎ = 1
//let ♈️ = 1
//let ♉️ = 1
//let ♊️ = 1
//let ♋️ = 1
//let ♌️ = 1
//let ♍️ = 1
//let ♎️ = 1
//let ♏️ = 1
//let ♐️ = 1
//let ♑️ = 1
//let ♒️ = 1
//let ♓️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚛ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☢ = 1
//let ☣ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
//let ✴️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ㊙️ = 1
let ㊗️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⛔️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❌ = 1
//let ⭕️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ♨️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ❗️ = 1
//let ❕ = 1
//let ❓ = 1
//let ❔ = 1
//let ‼️ = 1
//let ⁉️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚜ = 1
let 〽️ = 1
//let ⚠️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ♻️ = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ❇️ = 1
//let ✳️ = 1
//let ❎ = 1
//let ✅ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ➿ = 1
let  = 1
let Ⓜ️ = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ♿️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let 0️⃣ = 1
//let 1️⃣ = 1
//let 2️⃣ = 1
//let 3️⃣ = 1
//let 4️⃣ = 1
//let 5️⃣ = 1
//let 6️⃣ = 1
//let 7️⃣ = 1
//let 8️⃣ = 1
//let 9️⃣ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ▶️ = 1
//let ⏸ = 1
//let ⏯ = 1
//let ⏹ = 1
//let ⏺ = 1
//let ⏭ = 1
//let ⏮ = 1
//let ⏩ = 1
//let ⏪ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ◀️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ⏫ = 1
//let ⏬ = 1
//let ➡️ = 1
//let ⬅️ = 1
//let ⬆️ = 1
//let ⬇️ = 1
//let ↗️ = 1
//let ↘️ = 1
//let ↙️ = 1
//let ↖️ = 1
//let ↕️ = 1
//let ↔️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ↪️ = 1
//let ↩️ = 1
//let ⤴️ = 1
//let ⤵️ = 1
//let #️⃣ = 1
//let *️⃣ = 1
let ℹ️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let 〰️ = 1
//let ➰ = 1
//let ✔️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ➕ = 1
//let ➖ = 1
//let ➗ = 1
//let ✖️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ©️ = 1
//let ®️ = 1
let ™️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ☑️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ⚪️ = 1
//let ⚫️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
//let ▪️ = 1
//let ▫️ = 1
//let ⬛️ = 1
//let ⬜️ = 1
let  = 1
//let ◼️ = 1
//let ◻️ = 1
//let ◾️ = 1
//let ◽️ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let ️ = 1
//let ♠️ = 1
//let ♣️ = 1
//let ♥️ = 1
//let ♦️ = 1
let  = 1
let ‍ = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
let  = 1
```

Comment: All unicode code points available for identifiers are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID412). (I'm not sure this list is accurate and up-to-date.) As you see, some code points grouped as Dingbats can be an identifier: `let ❶ = 2`.